# Let $G$ be group and $f:G\rightarrow G$ be automorphism. If $Z$ be centralizer group, prove that $f(z)=Z$.

Tags: group-theory, automorphism-group

Here's the complete problem.

Let $G$ be group and $f:G\rightarrow G$ be automorphism. Define a set $Z=\lbrace z \in G | zg=gz, \forall g \in G \rbrace$ and $f(Z)=\lbrace F(z)|z \in Z \rbrace.$ Prove that $f(z)=Z$.

Here I tried.

Firstly, did the notation $F(z)$ on $f(Z)=\lbrace F(z)| z \in Z \rbrace$ should be change by $f(z)$ and on $f(z)=Z$, $f(z)$ should be change by $f(Z)$? If, no, I can't solve it.

If yes, I can solve it and here it is.

We'll show that $f(Z)=Z$.

Let $x \in f(Z)$. Then, $f^{-1}(x) = Z$ such that $f^{-1}(x)g=gf^{-1}(x)$. Since $f(f^{-1}(x)g)=xf(g)=f(g)x=f(gf^{-1}(x)$, then $x \in Z$. Hence, $f(Z) \subseteq Z$.

Conversely, let $y \in Z$ such that $yg=gy$. Since $f^{-1}(yg)=f^{-1}(y)f^{-1}(g) = f^{-1}(g)f^{-1}(y)$

$= f^{-1}(gy)$, then $f^{-1}(y) \in Z$ and implies that $y \in f(Z)$. Hence, $Z \subseteq f(Z)$.

Hence, $f(Z)=Z$.

Thanks for correction and help in advanced.

Comment: They must have meant to say $f(Z) = \{ f(z) | z\in Z \}$ (and show $f(Z) =Z$). And it seems like your proof is fine except for when you said $f^{-1}(x) = Z$, the correct statement would be $f^{-1}(x) \in Z$.

Comment: great, thanks for correction.

Comment: $Z$ is usually called “the center of $G$”, not the “centralizer group”.

Answer (score 2):

You're proving the *center* is *characteristic*.

This should be pretty straight forward:  $x\in Z\iff xg=gx,\,\forall g\iff f(g)f(x)=f(gx)=f(xg)=f(x)f(g)\iff f(x)\in Z$.

I couldn't quite follow your proof.  But the change from $z$ to $x$ is probably a good move.

Comment: what about if $f(x) \in Z \Rightarrow f^{-1}(x) \in Z$ since $f$ is function?

Comment: That does follow.  Everything seems to be reversible.  Correct me if I'm wrong.  Remember $f$ is an automorphism, so a bijection.